# WScript.Arguments issue

Tags: vbscript

I have a VBScript:

```
Set objUser = GetObject("WScript.Arguments.Item(0)")

objUser.TerminalServicesProfilePath = WScript.Arguments.Item(1) 
objUser.AllowLogon = Enabled 
objUser.SetInfo
```

This is called by:

```
wscript LDAPTSChanger.vbs LDAP://cn=Scott.Test,ou=Administration,dc=JPddRESS,dc=CO,dc=UK SCOMANTEST
```

But I can't get it to accept the `WScript.Arguments.Item(0)` as the search base (this will change per what's outputted elsewhere).

There is a space after the `ldaptschanger.vbs` to say its a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the quotes:

```
Set objUser = GetObject(WScript.Arguments.Item(0))
```